# Type '{ typecode: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'. // Angular 9.1.15, TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, typeahead

I do not have good idea about angular, i am learning. Below i have attached my TS file. I am working on Auto complete search/Type ahead search and i am facing these errors.

<----------------Code-------------------->

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';   
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';    
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';    
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';    
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';    


import { BciImprintComponent, LogoutComponent, ModalWindowService, NavigationService, SidebarNavItem, } from '@bci-web-core/core';


@Component({   
  selector: 'app-root',   
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',   
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']   
})   
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {   
  //options: string[] = ['CytroPac', 'CytroBox', 'GoPakTM'];    
  objectOptions = [   
    { typecode: 'CytroPac' },   
    { typecode: 'CytroBox' },   
    { typecode: 'GoPakTM' }   
  ];   
  myControl = new FormControl();   
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;   

  title = 'Your application';   
  sidebarLinks: SidebarNavItem[] = [];   
  sidebarFooterLinks: SidebarNavItem[] = [   
    {   
      title: 'Maja Mustermann',   
      overlay: {   
        component: LogoutComponent,   
        config: { title: 'Do you want to logout?', onLogout: () => this.logout() }   
      },   
      icon: 'Bosch-Ic-user'   
    },   
    {   
      id: 'imprint',   
      cb: () => this.onAbout(),   
      title: 'Imprint',   
      icon: 'Bosch-Ic-information'   
    }   
  ];   

  constructor(private titleService: Title,   
              private navigationService: NavigationService,   
              private modalWindowService: ModalWindowService) {   
  }   

  ngOnInit() {   
    this.titleService.setTitle(this.title);   
    this.getSidebarLinks().subscribe(sidebarLinks => this.sidebarLinks = sidebarLinks);   
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(   
      startWith(''),   
      map(value => this._filter(value))   
    );   
  }   

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {   
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();   
    return this.objectOptions.filter(option =>   
      option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)   
    );   
  }      

  getSidebarLinks(): Observable<SidebarNavItem[]> {  
    return this.navigationService.getNavigationItems();   
  }   
 

  onAbout() {   
    this.modalWindowService.openDialogWithComponent(BciImprintComponent);   
  }  
  

}
```

<-------------------Error------------------------>

src/app/app.component.ts:65:5 - error TS2322: Type '{ typecode: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
Type '{ typecode: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
 return this.objectOptions.filter(option =>
   
  option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)

 );
```

src/app/app.component.ts:66:14 - error TS2339: Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type '{ typecode: string; }'.

```
 option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)
```

Comment: `filteredOptions` works with an array of string, and you give it an array like `objectOptions`, which is not strings. this is objects containing strings. So you may have to use the `map` operator to transform a list of objects into a list of string ?

Comment: option.typecode.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)

Comment: Can you elaborate? TBH i do not have idea about map. Like how should use `map` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the type definitions, I'd guess you're passing a `string` and want to filter the array of objects based on it. You'd then need to return array of objects instead of array of strings.

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Try the following

```js
private _filter(value: string): string[] {   
  const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
  return this.objectOptions
    .map(objectOption => objectOption.option) // produces ['CytroPac', 'CytroBox', 'GoPakTM']
    .filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))
    .map(option => ({ typecode: option }));   // map back to array of objects
}
```

Or to use your existing implementation of the `_filter` function, you could use the commented out `options` variable (array of strings) instead of the array of objects `objectOptions`.

#### Update: using only `Array#filter`

See the comment by @Random below to use only the `Array#filter` without the need for redundant `Array#map`s.

Comment: Why do you map it twice ? You could simply use `objectOption.option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)` in the filter method instead ?

Comment: @Random: You're right, I actually misunderstood what the OP wanted yet produced the result they required. You could post an answer only using the `Array#filter`.

Comment: `return this.objectOptions   
      .map(objectOption => objectOption.typecode)   
      .filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue)    
    );`                                                                                                                                                    I added this, and i am getting desired output. Should i change as you suggested?